# Timber: archive-post_type.php not firing; equivalent in non-Timber themes works

Tags: wordpress, timber

Using [Timber](https://www.upstatement.com/timber/), I'm trying to render a custom archive page for my custom post type. CPT is `person`, and I'm simply trying to render **archive-person.php** when visiting "mysite.com/person". No matter what I do, all I get is the output of **archive.php**, never **archive-person.php**.

Yes, I *have* been hitting 'Save' on permalinks as many people suggest.

As a test, using WP's 2020 base theme, I made an equivalent **archive-post_type.php** in the classic WordPress way, and everything works fine. This is indicating my cpt's and permalinks are ok, and the issue perhaps has to do with my Timber-based theme specifically.

I've tried changing my CPT name properties to make sure I'm not creating permalink conflicts.

Timber views/partials, pages, singles and **single-post_type.php** are all rendering fine.

Other than tinkering with archive*.php pages, what's the first thing I should be looking at? Within functions.php Timber initialization, anything major that would specifically affect archives only?

**UPDATE:** In writing this post I see what could be an issue. Do I have to register my CPTs and taxonomies explicitly through Timber init, for it to be fully aware of them?

**archive.php (very similar to one from [Timber starter theme](https://github.com/timber/starter-theme/blob/master/archive.php))**

```
<?php

use Timber\Timber;

global $paged;

if ( ! isset( $paged ) || ! $paged ) {
    $paged = 1;
}

$templates = array( 'pages/archive.twig', 'pages/index.twig' );

$context = Timber::context();
$context['title'] = 'Archive';
if ( is_day() ) {
    $context['title'] = 'Archive: ' . get_the_date( 'D M Y' );
} elseif ( is_month() ) {
    $context['title'] = 'Archive: ' . get_the_date( 'M Y' );
} elseif ( is_year() ) {
    $context['title'] = 'Archive: ' . get_the_date( 'Y' );
} elseif ( is_tag() ) {
    $context['title'] = single_tag_title( '', false );
} elseif ( is_category() ) {
    $context['title'] = single_cat_title( '', false );
    array_unshift( $templates, 'archive-' . get_query_var( 'cat' ) . '.twig' );
} elseif ( is_post_type_archive() ) {
    $context['title'] = post_type_archive_title( '', false );
    array_unshift( $templates, 'archive-' . get_post_type() . '.twig' );
}

// Grabs everything on the site, regular posts and CPT's.
$context['posts'] = new \Timber\PostQuery();

    // Just for testing, to check if "person" posts can at least be rendered via archive.php. They do.
    //$args    = ['post_type' => 'person'];
    //$context['posts'] = new \Timber\PostQuery($args);

Timber::render( $templates, $context );

?>
```

**archive-person.php** Just a pared-down version of archive.php, with 'person' forced as post_type (as opposed to grabbing *all* posts):

```
use Timber\Timber;

global $paged;

if ( ! isset( $paged ) || ! $paged ) {
    $paged = 1;
}

$templates = array( 'pages/archive-person.twig' );

$context = Timber::context();
$context['title'] = 'Archive: Person';

$args    = [
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'post_type' => 'person',
];

$context['posts'] = new \Timber\PostQuery($args);

Timber::render( $templates, $context );
```

**functions.php**

```
class mySite extends Timber\Site {
    public function __construct() {
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
        add_theme_support( 'menus' ); 

        add_filter( 'timber_context', array( $this, 'add_to_context' ) );
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function add_to_context( $context ) {
        $context['menu'] = new \Timber\Menu('main-menu');
        $context['site'] = $this;

        return $context;
    }
}

new mySite();

function create_posttypes() {

      register_post_type( 'person',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Persons' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Person' )
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'show_in_rest' => true,
                'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' )
            )
        );

}

add_action( 'init', 'create_posttypes' );
```

Answer (score 0):

what you did seems enough to me, however add this to your functions.php to force the identification of your new post type

```
add_action('init', 'person_archive_rewrite');

function person_archive_rewrite(){
   add_rewrite_rule('^person/?','index.php?post_type=person','top');
}
```

then hit save permalink

keep me updated

Comment: Tried, and still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to add the code you wrote to register your custom post type 'person'? The default archive setting `has_archive` is false when you register a CPT - make sure that's set to true. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#has_archive